# Output escaped data in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, escaping, laravel-5

I am inserting escaped data in database using core PHP.

```
$collect = $conn->real_escape_string($value);
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (collect) VALUES ('$collect')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo ' : New record created successfully ';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Records are created successfully. But when I output data from same database using laravel 5.1, it shows weird characters like â€œ and â€ instead of "". I am outputting data like this in .blade.php file.

```
@foreach ($data as $d)
    {{ $d->collect }}<br />
@endforeach
```

If I output data using core PHP then output is perfect. In core PHP I am outputting data like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT  collect FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " collect: ".$row["collect"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

How can I output data using laravel 5 correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try following to output data without escaping.

```
{!! $d->collect !!}
```

`{{}}` will escape the text.

Comment: I tried that but with no success. I am escaping value before putting it in database.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced “ and ” with " and it is working fine. I didn't notice it first.